# ¿Cómo poner una vista anual con FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, fullcalendar

Estoy usando [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) para mostrar un calendario en mi sitio web. Ahora mismo sólo me muestra las vistas de mes, semana y día por defecto:

[image: Vista de FullCalendar]

Pero yo quiero que me muestre una vista del año también. ¿Existe alguna opción o función del FullCalendar que permita ver el año entero con todos los meses (a ser posible en español)?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de FullCalendar usas? Va a depender mucho de eso.

Answer (score 2):

Este es el ejemplo para mostrar el año :-)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'year,month,basicWeek,basicDay'
   },
   defaultView: 'year',
   editable: true,
   eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
   
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/monkbroc/fullcalendar/year-view-demo/dist/fullcalendar.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href="https://rawgit.com/monkbroc/fullcalendar/year-view-demo/dist/fullcalendar.css"/>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: no esta en la API pero si es una opción del plugin, interesante! no lo probé! :D ya aprendí algo nuevo de este plugin

Answer (score 2):

Sí, pero va a depender de la versión de FullCalendar que uses... y puede que te toque pagar.

El paquete de FullCalendar viene con diferentes vistas por defecto. [En la versión 1 del plugin, están limitadas a cinco](https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/views/Available_Views/), ninguna de las cuales representa años (traducción mía):

> FullCalendar tiene un número de diferentes "vistas", o modos de mostrar los días y eventos. Las siguientes 5 vistas están disponibles en FullCalendar:
>
> - month - [ver ejemplo](https://fullcalendar.io/views/month/)
> - basicWeek - [ver ejemplo](https://fullcalendar.io/views/basicWeek/) (disponible desde la versión 1.3)
> - basicDay - [ver ejemplo](https://fullcalendar.io/views/basicDay/) (disponible desde la versión 1.3)
> - agendaWeek - [ver ejemplo](https://fullcalendar.io/views/agendaWeek/) (disponible desde la versión 1.4)
> - agendaDay - [ver ejemplo](https://fullcalendar.io/views/agendaDay/) (disponible desde la versión 1.4)

Esas cinco vistas se extendieron a [nueve en las versiones 2 y 3 de FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/) (traducción mía):

> Las siguientes 9 vistas están incluidas en FullCalendar:
>
> - month - [ver ejemplo](https://fullcalendar.io/views/month/)
> - basicWeek - [ver ejemplo](https://fullcalendar.io/views/basicWeek/)
> - basicDay - [ver ejemplo](https://fullcalendar.io/views/basicDay/)
> - agendaWeek - [ver ejemplo](https://fullcalendar.io/views/agendaWeek/)
> - agendaDay - [ver ejemplo](https://fullcalendar.io/views/agendaDay/)
> - listYear
> - listMonth
> - listWeek
> - listDay
>
> Las siguientes vistas están incluidas en el [add-on premium Scheduler](https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/):
>
> - timelineDay
> - timelineWeek
> - timelineMonth
> - timelineYear

Por lo que sí existe un modo para mostrar los eventos en modo año (`listYear`), pero será en la forma de una lista y no un calendario en sí. Además, si pagas por usar el add-on Scheduler (sólo para versiones 2 y 3) entonces tendrás un modo más para año: `timelineYear`.

Answer (score 1):

No tienes la opcion de vista por año pero si tienes la opcion de una "agenda por año".

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'listYear,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    locale: 'es', //esto para cambiar el idioma al español
```

**NOTA:**

Para cambiar el idioma debes agregar lo siguiente:

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.2.0/locale-all.js